# What module is PYSIGNAL defined in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt

All of the examples I read online use

```
from PyQt4 import *
```

or some variant of that, importing everything. I don't want to do this, but I can't find where PYSIGNAL is defined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
PyQt4.Qt.SIGNAL
```

This is the same as:

```
PyQt4.QtCore.SIGNAL
```

Comment: No, there is a function called PYSIGNAL. http://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/x1408

Comment: @floogads, I'm pretty sure that's not about PyQt4.  Note that they're [using](http://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/c883) a 2001 version of Python, and the qt (not PyQt4) module.

Comment: Huh, forget it I suppose. I just tried the normal SIGNAL and it worked exactly like PYSIGNAL. Strange..